# PYTHON recursive sum of numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def recSum(list):
    if len(list)==0:
         return 0
    else:
         return list[0] + recSum(list[1:])

getSum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

How do I add an extra argument(p) which stops the recursion in index p?
for example having the list [1,2,3,4,5] and I want to have the sum till index[3]?

Comment: dont call variables `list` - that name is used by the build in

Comment: slice it: `getSum([1,2,3,4,5][:p])` - or provide `p` to your function as parameter and slice it inside using a helper to do the summing

Comment: `def recSum(lst, n): return 0 if not n else lst[0] + recSum(lst[1:], n-1)`

Comment: You've described at least half of the implementation already.  Make a coding attempt and post *that* problem.  "How do I code a solution to this problem" gets into tutorial areas beyond the bounds of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @coldspeed there is one problem with your suggestion.

Comment: your code doesnt take n as an index but as the number in the list. So index[1] would be the first number of the list

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it recursively, create a helper with a parameter to keep track of what index you're on:

```
def recSum(list, p):
    recSumHelper(list, p, 0)

def recSumHelper(list, p, idx):
    if len(list)==0 or idx > p:
         return 0
    else:
         return list[0] + recSumHelper(list[1:], p, idx + 1)

getSum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that can operate over all generators and not only arrays, `itertools` helps:

```
import itertools

def recSum(data, cutoff):
    return sum( itertools.islice(data, cutoff))
```